# mh_make and resolving pom dependencies

Tags: maven, debian, pom.xml, packaging

let's consider the case mh_make showing us a lot of dependencies. now we try mvn install which installs all plugins to ~/.m2/repository . but that is not picked up and again we see mh_make searching jars in /usr/share/maven-repo and throwing error

in this link [maven-repo-helper](https://github.com/Debian/maven-repo-helper/blob/master/doc/repository.rst) - "All dependencies must be available as Debian packages and it is not acceptable to download artifacts during the build process from the central Maven repository."

1. are we supposed to search for deb package for each dependency in pom.xml?
2. if yes then what is use of .m2 repository and all the jars in it?
3. why does mh_make look only into /usr/share/maven-repo or which is the export variable which points it. changing $REPO is not making it look into ~/.m2/repository
4. why do we need a deb package for a pom jar dependency if at all we need it.

Answer (score 0):

An answer was posted on the debian-java list:
https://lists.debian.org/debian-java/2014/11/msg00011.html